# probleme while Create Message Channel

Tags: lightning-web-components, superbadges, lightning-message-channel

i am trying to create a Message Channel so i can finish the trailhead superbadge :

i created an XML File :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <LightningMessageChannel xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<description>This is a sample Lightning Message Channel for the Lightning Web Components 
     Superbadge.</description>
   <isExposed>true</isExposed>
  <lightningMessageFields>
    <description>This is the record Id that changed</description>
    <fieldName>recordId</fieldName>
 </lightningMessageFields>
 <masterLabel>BoatMessageChannel</masterLabel>
</LightningMessageChannel>
```

when i execute the commande : sfdx force:source:deploy

i have this error message

**ERROR running force:source:deploy:  Missing one of the following parameters: manifest, metadata, sourcepath, validateddeployrequestid**

can someone help me please i didn't do anything except creating the project, the messageChannel folder and the file **BoatMessageChannel.messageChannel-meta.xml**

Regards

Amir

Comment: Have you authorized against the org (Trailhead Playground)?

Comment: i found the issue, i was using the wrong playground

Comment: thank you Victor :)

Comment: You are welcome!